# WordPress admin id change automatically. what can i do?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

i have a three WordPress website running my own theme. admin id user name change automatically in my database. what can i go. change id name is shun403.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your site's **database**, you can go to `wp_users` table (or if you have given any other prefix the table name should be `{prefix}_users`) and change the `user_login` value for the particular user to whatever you like.

Comment: i can access my database. change user name manually. after few hours the user name change automatically. how i prevent that

Comment: From the username you have provided `shun43` it sounds like your site may be hacked. Can you check what is coming in `your_url/Hacked-by-Shun403/`

Comment: everything is OK. only admin id user name change.. i check the url currentbdnews24.com/hacked-by-shun403 is not found

Comment: This is only possible if someone else has access to your server or database. Try disabling your plugins and see. Check if your plugins originals. Try changing your database password. Or scan your website using plugins like securi or wordfence. Check if the server is not hacked. Probably it is better have a chat with your hosting provider and see.